# Trying to get property of non-object error on laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

(2/2) ErrorException
Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\bgcbus\resources\views\usercrud\sendView.blade.php)

```
Visit `https://pastebin.com/wuV2zzhp` for link of the complete code that I 
think that took part on the token sending or verification process.
```

I want my application to send a verification token to email address of new users(only the admin of the system can add new users)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocrmV.png)

Comment: Link isnt working

Comment: https://pastebin.com/wuV2zzhp Thank you!

Comment: no one is going to read ur code outside here.

update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ErrorException Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\bgcbus\resources\views\usercrud\sendView.blade.php)

This error indicates that the bug is coming from your `sendView.blade.php` view file, which you've stated has the following content:

```
TO veerify <a href="{{ route('sendEmailDone', ["email" => $user->email,"verifyToken"=>$user->verifyToken]) }}" click here />
```

The only object being accessed in this view is `$user`. Let's see if we can figure out why it isn't an object.

Your `sendView` view is being loaded through the `verifyEmail` Mailable. When loading a view via a Mailable, its [view data](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mail#view-data) can be pulled from the public properties of the Mailable. Your Mailable *does* have `public $user;` defined, so it should be sent to the view. So why isn't it an object?

Assuming you've pasted the exact content of your Mailable, there appears to be a typo in your constructor:

```
public function __construct(User $user)
{
    //
    $this->userC=$user;
}
```

This is saving the supplied `User` object to the public property `$userC`, **not** `$user`.